# Canvas state save Android

Tags: android, canvas

In my android code onDraw method is called again and again after 5ms. I want to redraw on image and want one image static on one positon. But the problem is when OnDraw is called again It redraws both images. I want it to redraw only one image not the ohter one. This is my OnDraw Method

```
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawBitmap(mVolleyBall, cx, cy, null); // Image to be redrawn

            canvas.drawBitmap(red,x, y, null); //  Static image
}
```

Answer (score 0):

when ever OnDraw will be called it will draw the content defined in that method.
So you need to define coordinate in both images, where they need to be placed.
As per your requirement coordinates of one image need to be fixed and other will updates with new x,y.

Answer (score -1):

My suggestion, make a boolean variable which only lets it happen once. Like this:

```
`protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
     canvas.drawBitmap(mVolleyBall, cx, cy, null); // Image to be redrawn
        if(!once){
        canvas.drawBitmap(red,x, y, null); //  Static image
        once = true        
        }
}`
```

With the variable once being declared as false somewhere in your initialization.

Comment: When next time onDraw is called it removes the previous image, the static one, and only draw the new one

Comment: If you want to only draw the image once you may want to look into fragmenting your application. I don't have much experience with it but it may solve your issue: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

Comment: OnDraw() method will redraw content in every call, hence using if(!once) will refresh view with one image only.